# Cannot print on printer Olivetti PR 4 SL

Tags: c#, .net, printing, serial-port

I'm trying to print on Olivetti PR 4 SL. In of out .NET application ("Print Test Page", Word, ...) it works. But in my .NET application, it doesn't.
This is my simplified code:

```
using (var serialPort = new SerialPort())
{
    serialPort.PortName = "COM1";  // Where the printer is installed.
    serialPort.Open();
    serialPort.Write("Hello world!");
}
```

The error message is:

> The given port name does not start with COM/com or does not resolve to
>   a valid serial port. Parameter name: portName

Would anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to finalize the character stream which are sent to the printer by NEW_LINE (ASCII code is 10).
You can use the following line of code in order to print;

```
serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 10 });
```